# Show that the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}| f(x)=x\}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}| f(x)=x\}$ is closed, assuming that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. So here is my attempt:

Let $\{x_k\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_k \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}| f(x)=x\}$ and $x_k \to x$ as $k \to \infty$.Then, as $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous by a theorem in my text, the sequence $\{y_k\}$ where $\{y_k\} = f(x_k)$ converges to $f(x)$. So we have that $f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x_k) =x $.  So by definition $x$ is in the set, and we can conclude now that since the set contains all of its limit points, that the set is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I have a feeling I made some flaws in logic somewhere around here, any help is appreciated. I only want some hints on what I did wrong so I can think about the problem longer instead of just having the solution.

Comment: You are confusing the limit of a sequence or of function with that silly limit point thing.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your argument. You may want to say $f(x_k)=x_k$ for all $k$ for the sake of completeness, but it looks fine with me. For a slicker approach, read the answer provided by @APCorreia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$. Since $f$ is continuous, $g$ is continuous as well.

Once $\{0\}$ is closed, we conclude that $g^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x) = x\}$ is closed, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I like that a lot, its very elegant

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine, but I would write it differently, plus I'll add missing details:

Let $C=\{x\in \Bbb R\mid f(x) =x\}$. To show $C$ is closed we take a sequence $(x_n)_n \to x$ with $x_n \in C$ for all $n$ and we show $x$ is in $C$ as well (so $C$ is closed under sequential limits, which is enough to show closedness in all metric spaces).

As $f$ is continuous, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ as well. But, as $x_n \in C$, $f(x_n) = x_n$ and so $f(x)=x$ because *limits of sequences are unique* (here we are using a property of metric spaces again (Hausdorffness): we have the same sequence $(x_n)$ both converging to $x$ and $f(x)$; in a non-metric space we *could* have $x \neq f(x)$ ) and as $f(x)=x$, $x \in C$ by definition and we're done.

FWIW (and for your later study): this proof would straightforwardly generalise to all Hausdorff topological spaces (a much wider class than just $\Bbb R$), using nets instead of sequences.